# Lost some text when extracting pdf

Tags: pdf, itext

I've tried to get all the text on the page by using `iText`, but I have no idea why every coordinate text loses the last two character.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(@"E:\Coding\COOR.pdf"));
LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strategy);
parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfDoc.GetFirstPage());
Console.Write(strategy.GetResultantText());
pdfDoc.Close();

Console.WriteLine("Great!");
Console.ReadKey();
```

You can also download my code from
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Al1hUSZtR4OjwU3XVBRQGneVaZlS

Comment: You could post your code how you tried to get the text

Comment: Yeah, the attachment link, you can click "test files", which includes pdf file and code file.

Comment: You are supposed to post your code inside your question, not as an attachment. The code should be short, compileable, and reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the code in the download location to the question.

Comment: Wow, much better. Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In short

The reason for that "lost text" is that the missing "text" isn't there to start with!

#### In detail

The contents of you PDF file are constructed in a misleading manner.

On the one hand there are very many path definitions which then are stroked (drawn). These drawings create what you can *see* in a viewer, both text and table lines.

On the other hand there are a few text drawing instructions to draw text using text rendering mode 3 which is... *invisible*! These drawings create the text you can *copy&paste* in a viewer or *extract* using iText.

Unfortunately the text in the text drawing instructions and the text drawn using paths does not match completely. The text you retrieve via copy&paste or text extraction, therefore, differs from your expectations.

Also the glyph sizes and positions are not exactly the same

To illustrate this I made the text drawing instructions use the normal (fill) text rendering mode. The top left corner which originally looks like this:

[image: top left corner]

with that change looks like this:

[image: top left corner, text made visible]

As you see the formerly invisible text is only approximately at the same position as the visible drawings, and it is somewhat broken: The symbol for degrees is weirdly represented as "¡ã", and the longitude fractional seconds and the following symbol for seconds are missing.

---

To correctly extract the originally visible data, you'll need to use OCR instead of text extraction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,@mkl

Comment: The invisible text was deleted by Adobe Acrobat before I uploaded the pdf. I haven't noticed the deleted text is still there. I guess the pdf file is created by autocad with shape font. I'm confused by the missing two characters of every coordinate string, which is very important for me.

Comment: *"I'm confused by the missing two characters of every coordinate string, which is very important for me"* - those two characters really are not there. They are not in the text drawing instructions of the pdf.